# How to prove the positivity of Fresnel-like integrals in the positive real axis

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality, fresnel-integrals

I need to prove the following inequality:
$$\int_0^x \sin(t^{\alpha})dt>0$$
for $x>0$ and $\alpha>1$.

I used Mathematica to plot the integrals for some values of $\alpha=2,4/3,3$ ($\alpha=2$ is the well-known Fresnel integral). It looks like the claim it correct. But I don't know how to prove it. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Can we use substitution $t^\alpha = s$?

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks

Comment: Nice to hear that!